# Ajax Form Submission Play Framework 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I've just started using the Play 2.0 Framwork. 
I wonder what is the best way to do ajax-based form submission. Currently my pages contains a form and a list below, where the new entries (of the form) should appear. I'd like to do the submission by ajax and also the list update.

But my first question is how to submit the form via ajax and use the form binding and the validation of the Controllers. Is that possible? What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

IMHO you could use play's JavaScript Routing functionality, js validation (e.g. jquery validator plugin) and server side validation. First declare case class that will serve as a domain object

```
case class SimpleUser( name: String, email: String )
```

then create controller with form and function:

```
object Users extends Controller{
    //validation 1 goes here
    val userForm = Form(
        mapping(
            "name" -> text,
            "email" -> email
        )(SimpleUser.apply)(SimpleUser.unapply)
    )

    def save = Action { implicit request =>
        userForm.bindFromRequest().fold(
            formWithErrors => {
                BadRequest( "uuuups" ) 
            },
            user => {
                //validation 2 goes here
                Ok( "ok" )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Once you have this, you add entries to routes file

```
POST    /users/save controllers.Users.save
GET     /jsroutes   controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes
```

and in Application controller

```
def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
    import routes.javascript._
    Ok(
        Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
            Users.save
    ) ).as("text/javascript")
}
```

And now the JavaScript part

```
(...)
save: function(){
    jsRoutes.controllers.Users.save().ajax( {
        data: jQuery( 'form' ).serialize(),
        success: function( data ){
            //refresh users' list
        },
        error: function( data ){
            console.log( data.responseText );
        }
    });
}
```

It's just simple example (and I didn't compile it), but shows the idea.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way is jQuery. Just need to [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) your form and send it with common [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). In response your method should sent a JSON data containing ie. new items and other stuff like custom status etc.

Comment: Ok, so I have to display the validation messages and so on all on my own? Sad, but maybe I'm spoilt by Wicket :)

Comment: If you were sending form with common POST you could redirect the user beck to the form-page if Form `hasErrors()`, and then built-in form helpers displays constraints and errors automatically,  anyway if you're sending it with AJAX I think that you should use a jQuery's validation plugin before the sending, and if you require to make server-side validation, yes, you'll need to transport error messages in response and display them with JS.

Comment: yup your spoiled by wicket. I am also coming from wicket so I know what you feel like. Wicket ajax form submission also used javascript under the hood - any returned feedback messages would be parsed by a client side wicket javascript and appended to the right place. now you have to to this process manually :(